# Testosterone levels. Fighters vs Bodybuilders

Tags: testosterone

Who have the higher average testosterone levels? I know that bodybuilding boosts testosterone due to its exercises but what about fighters? All this danger they face.. not necessarily being afraid but there is certain amount of danger in fighting which stimulates the production of T. For example I've noticed before when preparing for a fight or when I am in any danger in general I can lift close to 2 times more weight and can endure much more, let's say doing push-ups for this example. This is clear sign of testosterone being produced from my body. There are many other examples that I can write about before fight preparation but you get the idea.

On the other hand preparing for fighting can be very exhausting which lowers T levels at the time.

So who are the guys with higher average levels of T?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has more or less nothing to do with testosterone. You can lift more weight when you feel like you're in "danger" because of **adrenaline**. Basically, when you do weight training, your body and CNS only let you exert a certain percentage of your total muscular contractions. This is because your body is trying to make sure you don't get injured by applying more force than you can actually handle. When you have an adrenaline spike, your body lets you increase this percentage that I mentioned above, and therefore you can use more of your total strength. This has nothing to do with testosterone. For example, I'm sure you've heard of mothers lifting/pushing cars in order to save their babies etc...

Now to answer your actual question, if we are talking professional level of bodybuilding and fighting, then it is bodybuilding WITHOUT QUESTION. At the pro level of bodybuilding, you can be sure that at least 90% of the athletes are supplementing with anabolic steroids, which are just derivatives of the testosterone compound. For example, on average a young male will produce somewhere around 6mg of testosterone per day. Now, a bodybuilder trying to turn pro, or already pro, will supplement with MINIMUM 500mg of testosterone a week!

Now, if the bodybuilder is natural, then it could go either way. The amount of testosterone that an individual has will largely be impacted by genetics and their lifestyle. What I mean by lifestyle is largely composed of their diet and sleep. The training won't have much effect, given that both of them are doing some form of strength and high intensity training. Keep in mind however, that the fatter a person is, means the more estrogen they will have (opposite of testosterone basically).

I hope that answers more or less all your concerns.

Answer (score -2):

Brofessor offers a very accurate insigh. Let's build on that - assuming the question is asked with the assumption that 'the more testosterone, the better' -

Testosterone is a hormone that requires certain things to be produced in the body. It also converts to other things when there is too much.

When young and healthy (lifestyle and general health),  it peaks in the morning and drops through the day. This is sometimes less dramatic or relevant later in life. Yes, certain things can alter levels throughout the day (and on average) - research tends to imply higher levels yield a leaner body. Lower levels yield higher body fat and may also signal the presence of a bad habit, poor health or something else that may have to be addressed.

Guys with higher levels are typically those who aren't seniors... Or  those whom are young (and/or) healthy (and/or) physically fit. Also included would be those taking artificial testosterone ... And a portion of balding guys with gyno or balding due to having too much for ANY reason.

So, who has more social skills? A politician or a business man? Are social skills relevant if you are not in an environment with tons of people? What if you're unable to communicate because you can't talk or write? What if you have no social skills, but had them earlier in life - so you have more friends and relationships regardless.

My intention is not to discredit the roll of testosterone. You ask a great question. Just illustrating that it's most important to reach your own potential and not match someone else's.

Comment: What research "research tends to imply higher levels yield a leaner body"?